# Efficiently keep different data structures synchronised - tree, list of objects

Tags: design-patterns, python, synchronization, trees

## Problem description

I have a pet project to translate TEI XML to standoff JSON and back: https://github.com/standoff-nlp/standoffconverter and I am currently thinking about a rewrite/restructuring.
The standoff representation is a collection of objects that is separate from the content of the document. Each object represents one XML annotation and stores the beginning and end character of the content of the document that it spans.

The main use case for this software is when a user has a collection of TEI XML documents and wants to convert, visualize or modify it. The standard way is to use `xpath` (for example with `lxml`) But for some use cases, it is a lot nicer to have a standoff representation.

Therefore, currently, I always have both data structures present.
This is `AnnotationPair` which contains the standoff element and the tree node:
https://github.com/standoff-nlp/standoffconverter/blob/master/standoffconverter/standoffs.py#L103

The challenges that I face are the following:

- The standoff representation does not inherently fulfil the tree characteristic
- There is (at least to me) no intuitive way to query the `AnnotationPair` collection with both, XPATH and list comprehension.
- When modifying one data structure, the other one also has to be modified:

Practically, in the `master` this is currently solved by just converting the whole document again. Either from standoff to etree or from etree to standoff - depending of which of the two representation has changed. (You can see the current implementation here:

- https://github.com/standoff-nlp/standoffconverter/blob/master/standoffconverter/standoffs.py#L19
- and https://github.com/standoff-nlp/standoffconverter/blob/master/standoffconverter/standoffs.py#L61

Especially when the documents are large or the modifications are small, this is awfully inefficient.

Another aspect of the inefficiency comes from the fact that the `etree` actually uses a more performant `C` implementation for the data structure and my standoff represenation is in pure python.

## Questions

### On an abstract level, what is the best way to represent the data?

- Should I have both structures and synchronize them?
- Should I only have one persistent structure and the other one always gets translated? If yes: which one?
- Is there a third option?
- Especially, when I started to apply modifications to the other structure when the one gets modified, the code starts to become more and more complicated. But recreating the whole data structure is, as I said already, not feasable for large documents (or a lot of modifications).

### Are there off-the-shelf solutions to have synchronized data structures?

I am for example thinking of a data base solution that has different e.g. views of the data. Is there a solution specifically for tree and standoff?

### (Bonus Question) Is there a way to combine xpath-like queries with filter queries on the standoff representation?

As you can see, the AnnotationPair already has an `xpath` function https://github.com/standoff-nlp/standoffconverter/blob/master/standoffconverter/standoffs.py#L136
However, the main issue that this currently has (there may be more but this is the one I am aware of) is that the logic of the remaining text/tail is different between XML and standoff. For example if the xpath filters out elements with `not()` the text inside the elements would also be discarded. However if I filter out subelements in the standoff structure, the text would still be present within the parent element.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend having just one internal representation and not try to synchronise. Since the physical file format is XML, the etree is likely the better format to be the canonical representation.

Instead of transforming the XML into other data structure, instead I'd suggest you create an adaptor classes. The adaptor class can duck type to basic data structures like list and dict by implementing dunder methods like `__getitem__()`, `__setitem__()`, `__iter__()`, and/or `@property` that translates operations on the secondary representation to etree operations to provide an interface that is easier for the application to work with. For extra brownie points, you can have the adaptors implement the appropriate ABC (abstract base class).

Using an adaptor means that Objects related to the secondary representation are created lazily on-demand, rather than always being created and always needing to be converted. It also means that there's only one state to update, as the adaptors are stateless. You only need to create the adaptor objects for the parts of the tree that the application is working on, so making tiny changes in a big tree won't require converting the whole tree.

You'll need to be careful to avoid keeping any state on the adaptor objects. You either need a way to create a registry to avoid creating duplicate adaptor objects for the same parts of the tree (Singleton) or you need to put all significant state on the canonical representation so that duplicate adaptor will always share all state (Borg).